# Prove general statement to be true in all cases

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Question:** Explain why the following implication is true for any proposition P:

$\left(\forall x\right)P\Longrightarrow\left(\exists x\right)P$

You can assume that the universal set is not empty.

My approach: I want to prove that the antecedent is false no matter $P$ is in order for the statement to be true for any proposition $P$. Would you please give me a hint? Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think that's possible; what about the proposition $\text{True}$?

Comment: @thorimur it is a generalization of a more specific problem. My Professor said the statement is always true although it sounds confusing to me. There is two little information to be extracted to prove this.

Comment: ah, sorry, i specifically meant i don't think it's possible to show the antecedent is false for arbitrary $P$, as it's true for $P=\text{True}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a statement $P$.

That is, $P(x)$. Note that we may write $P$ this way even if it does not depend on $x$. Suppose $\forall x P(x)$ holds. Since your universal set is nonempty, this implies there is an x for which $P(x)$ holds. Hence, $\exists x P(x)$ holds. And the implication holds, since it can only fail if the first part is true while the second part false.

This is the basic intuition behind the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x=u$, where $u$ is an elemant of the universal set. Then $\forall x P$ implies $\models P[u]$ (since $\forall x P$ means that for any $x$ assignment $P$ is true). This gives $\exists xP$ (since $\exists x P$ means that for some $x$ assignment $P$ is true).